# Не срабатывает часть кода, отвечающая за то, чтобы не давать вводить определённые символы в определенную позицию текста

Tags: android, kotlin

ТЗ: для защиты от случайных нажатий не на те клавиши нужна проверка значения, например, 3-ей и 4-ой цифры в строке, чтобы 3 равнялась 0 или 1, а 4-я - 1 или 2. Если это не так - то выполнение кода должно просто приостанавливаться и не давать вводить следующие знаки.
Условие не срабатывает если объединить, по отдельности срабатывает, но выполнение кода не прерывается. Может дело в цикличности addTextChangedListener

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 slovo.setOnFocusChangeListener { _: View, hasFocus ->
     inputTextWatch()
 }

fun inputTextWatch() {

    slovo.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        var isAdded = true

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            isAdded = count < after
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            if (s.length == 4) {
                when (s[3].equals("0".single())) or (s[3].equals("1".single())) {
                    false -> {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Ошибка ввода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            return
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

            if (isAdded) {
                when (s.length) {
                    2 -> s.append(".")
                    5 -> s.append(".")
                }
            }

            var str = s.toString().replace(".", "")
            if (str.length > 2) {
                str = "${str.take(2)}.${str.drop(2)}"
            }
            if (str.length > 5) {
                str = "${str.take(5)}.${str.drop(5)}"
            }
            if (str != s.toString()) {
                s.replace(0, s.length, str)
            }
        }
    } )
}
```

Comment: У вас `override` функций происходит в функции `inputTextWatch()`?

Comment: Получается что так. Потому что этот код нужен только в 4-х одинаковых полях

Comment: А вы уверены, что `override` может быть объявлен в функции, а не в классе?

Comment: так работает же, во всем без проблем кроме этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {...`
```

следует добавить:

```
if (s.length == 4) {
    when (s[3].equals("0".single()) || s[3].equals("1".single())) {
        false -> {
            println(s[3])
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Ошибка ввода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            slovo.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(4))
        }
        true -> slovo.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
    }
}
```

Но есть небольшой нюанс в работе кода.  [Задам отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336603/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-println-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C), потому что на этот вопрос нашел ответ сам, хоть это возможно и не оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по кол-ву ваших сложностей и проблем возникающих с реализацией этого функционала у меня возник вопрос - почему нельзя использовать стандартный datePicker:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эту штуку можно если что кастомизировать и настроить. Добавьте клик слушатель на ваше поле, и просто выводите datepicker:

```
val dateSetListener = object : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int,
                                   dayOfMonth: Int) {
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                updateDateInView()
            }
        }



DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                        dateSetListener,
                        // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
                        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
```

вот есть [туториал](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-datepicker-kotlin-example/) и [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers). Дальше отключите возможность фокуса на поле для ввода типа такого:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

добавить на всякий случай:

```
android:inputType="date"
```

вот ещё один [туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/datepicker.php) на всякий случай. Дальше после выбора даты устанавливаете текст в ваше поле:

```
private fun updateDateInView() {
        val myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // mention the format you need
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
        textview_date!!.text = sdf.format(cal.getTime())
    }
```

и все. Не нужно будет лепить костыли для отлова того что пользователь ввел и тому подобное. Безусловно ваша попытка реализации тоже интересная, но нужно учитывать что вы данное решение должны будете поддерживать и оптимизировать. Поэтому мне кажется что данное решение тоже решит вашу задачу но будет проще для осознания и поддержки.

Comment: спасибо, но в силу специфичности пользовательского взаимодействия с программой datapicker не подходит. И дополнительно я изучаю основы программирования

Comment: это один из примеров реализации дата поля, есть и другие варианты, но уже с использованием xml, просто слишком высока вероятность что где-то что-то будет не работать, и искомое вами решение сделанное полностью самостоятельно может оказаться трудноподдерживаемым, найдите тогда библиотечку какую-то

Comment: вот вроде есть то что вам нужно - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sce4EKklwKE,  дальше немного подпилите под себя и будет норм

Comment: спасибо, за информацию! но это будет касаться не только ввода дат. Поэтому и нужен подобный алгоритм.  А так даже на нашем этом сайте есть уже примеры валидации дат и разные библиотеки. Но это не нужно пока.

Comment: так оно валидировать будет то что вы зададите, там есть маска которая будет подставляться

Comment: посмотрел - всё вроде просто но алгоритм не тот что мне нужен. Например - `if(mon > 12) mon = 12` - это не годится в моем случае (если дата), так как пользователь может ошибочно ввести цифры 22, программа их исправит на 12, а нужно было 02.... Пользователь не заметит исправления и расчет произойдет не верный!!!  Поэтому я и прошу помочь в моем коде - тут именно такая, логика, которую ещё в примерах не встречал. И на первый взгляд всё просто - остановить программу если цифра не та, что в условии